# Boost test summary report with failures?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-test

Is there a way to produce a summary report of failures in using Boost test? I know about the existing report options but they produce too much output. My basic problem is that my test suite has grown large enough that I can not longer find the failures in the output.

I would like something that writes the failures, and just the failures, after execution. Ideally it would include what check that failed, but if I could just get the name of the suite/test that'd be enough.

I'm okay with programming the summary myself, but I don't see anyway to gain access to the test results.  I know about the XML output option but that is not what I want. It would introduce another layer needlessly complicating my toolchain.

Comment: I know that you said that you are aware of the options, but what's wrong with `--report_level=confirm --log_level=nothing` ?

Comment: That doesn't report the failing cases, just gives a total count. I've tried using `--log_level=error` and it's the best option so far,though with a lot of debug output it can still be a problem.

Comment: Is it an option to post-process by piping to `grep` or `sed`?

Comment: Post-processing is what I want to avoid since it complicates my toolchain. I'd prefer to have it in-process.  (For post-processing I would simpyl use the XML output mode.)

Comment: @mockinterface, changing the log-level only partially helps. The problem is that it doesn't report in which test suite the problem is, only the line number and test name. This leaves me hunting down where it happened in my code.